# "_Exception" appended to the JAX-WS generated exception classes

Tags: jax-ws

I ran wsimport tool to create client code from wsdl, all client code generates as successfully, however, exception classes have wired names as follows.

```
ProductSupplierException_Exception.java
UnknownProductException_Exception.java
OutOfStockException_Exception.java
```

All exception classes have "_Exception" appended to the end of the class name.

using jdk: 1.6.

This is how i define exception in wsdl/xsd

***WSDL:***

```
<message name="InvalidDetailsException">
<part name="fault" element="tns:InvalidDetailsException"></part>
</message>
```

***XSD:***

```
<xs:element name="InvalidDetailsException" type="tns:InvalidDetailsException" />

<xs:complexType name="InvalidDetailsException">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wsimport` appends `_Exception` to the exception classes that generated from this WSDL, because their names is clashed.

See Also:

- [is there a way to avoid suffixing exception classes with "_Exception" ?](https://www.java.net/node/683481)